# How to get Notification if Marker gets inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Im trying to get a Notification if My marker gets into any of the polygons inside the map. However, can't seem to find a way to do it correctly, this is my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signin.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAjp8cvAcEYCwzuCyTQORL3Z1iQPdQMg_8",
            authDomain: "just-don-t.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://just-don-t.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "just-don-t",
            storageBucket: "just-don-t.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "925350346315"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.19.0.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjp8cvAcEYCwzuCyTQORL3Z1iQPdQMg_8&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" async defer>   </script>

<header><h1><center><b>WELCOME TO THE JUST DON'T APP</b> </center></h1></header>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
    <style >
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

           [...] Here is just visual parts of the app such as buttons and such, it should not affect the rest of the app [...]

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    var lineCoords = [];
    var pubnub = new PubNub({
        publishKey:   'pub-c-22289088-791b-4f24-900a-84dc41c860bf',
        subscribeKey: 'sub-c-e781e56c-23f5-11e8-a8f3-22fca5d72012'
    });
    window.lat = 55.845890;
    window.lng = -4.423741;
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updatePosition);
        }
        return null;
    };
    function updatePosition(position) {
        if (position) {
            window.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            window.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){updatePosition(getLocation());}, 10000);
    function currentLocation() {
        return {lat:window.lat, lng:window.lng};
    };


    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
            zoom: 17

        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map
        });
        var pleasantAreaCoords = [
            {lat: 55.84478883022466, lng:-4.423067882047013},
            {lat: 55.84485326696093, lng: -4.422505549698727},
            {lat: 55.84538931148452, lng: -4.4228536960804},
            {lat: 55.84525930830721, lng: -4.423344253807979},
            {lat: 55.84478883022466, lng: -4.423067882047013}
        ];
        var pleasant = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: pleasantAreaCoords,
            strokeColor: '#E9F52C',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#E9F52C',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        pleasant.setMap(map);

        var unsafeCoords = [
            {lat: 55.84582542929267, lng:-4.423879981040955 },
            {lat: 55.845723031335204, lng: -4.424362778663635},
            {lat: 55.84565677368958, lng:-4.424352049827576},
            {lat: 55.845723031335204, lng:-4.4238585233688354},
            {lat: 55.8458284409932, lng: -4.423881322145462}
        ]
        var unsafe_area = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: unsafeCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        unsafe_area.setMap(map);

        var unpleasantAreacoords = [
            {lat: 55.84580133567989,lng:-4.424523711204529},
            {lat: 55.84583747609345,lng: -4.424319863319397},
            {lat: 55.84653618415134,lng: -4.424673914909363},
            {lat: 55.8465000443874,lng: -4.425221085548401},
            {lat: 55.84580160878137,lng: -4.4245168063742994}
        ];
        var unpleasant = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: unpleasantAreacoords,
            strokeColor: '#F5942C',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#F5942C',
            fillOpacity: 0.35

        });
        unpleasant.setMap(map);

        var commercialZoneCoords = [
            {lat: 55.846999974806145,lng: -4.423676133155823},
            {lat: 55.84714453180107,lng: -4.421852231025696},
            {lat: 55.84583747609345,lng: -4.421680569648743},
            {lat: 55.84553630495364,lng: -4.423472285270691}
        ];
        var commercialZone = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: commercialZoneCoords,
            strokeColor: '#3CB2F1',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#3CB2F1',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        commercialZone.setMap(map);

        var mainStreetCoords =[
            {lat: 55.84504840275506,lng: -4.426873326301575},
            {lat: 55.84528331939289,lng: -4.4235581159591675},
            {lat: 55.84553028150705,lng: -4.423697590827942},
            {lat: 55.8452652489327,lng: -4.426959156990051}
        ];


        var mainStreet = new google.maps.Polygon({  paths: mainStreetCoords,
            strokeColor: '#E63CF1',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#E63CF1',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        mainStreet.setMap(map);


// Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var initialize = function() {
                    map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {center:{lat:lat,lng:lng},zoom:12});
                    mark = new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:lat, lng:lng}, map:map});
                };
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                window.initialize = initialize;
                var Paisley = pos;
                var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:{lat:lat, lng:lng},
                    map:map,
                });
                var redraw = function(payload) {
                    lat = payload.message.lat;
                    lng = payload.message.lng;
                    mark.setPosition({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});

                    lineCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
                    var lineCoordinatesPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: lineCoords,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#2E10FF'
                    });
                    lineCoordinatesPath.setMap(map);
                };
                point = position;

                var pnChannel = "map-channel";
                var pubnub = new PubNub({
                    publishKey:   'pub-c-22289088-791b-4f24-900a-84dc41c860bf',
                    subscribeKey: 'sub-c-e781e56c-23f5-11e8-a8f3-22fca5d72012'
                });
                pubnub.subscribe({channels: [pnChannel]});
                pubnub.addListener({message:redraw});
                map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});

                setInterval(function() {
                    pubnub.publish({channel:pnChannel, message:currentLocation()});
                }, 100);


            }, function () {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        }

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code Im trying to implement to detect and notify if the marker gets inside the polygon (for this example I am using

```
point = Marker
if(google.maps.containsLocation(point, mainStreetCoords) == true) {
alert("You are at the Main street");
}
```

If I get it to work will update this but would appreciate if someone could explain me how to get it to work.

Comment: What is `Marker`?  Where does it come from? Please provide a [mcve] that shows what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Google map api document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation?hl=zh-tw)

```
// This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src=".../maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">

google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle)
```

the first variable would be like this    `var point = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);`

but not a marker

so I tried your code (but mine google map api ;) )

add a click event and test, it works

here's working code

```
commercialZone.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e.latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            fillColor: "red",
            fillOpacity: .2,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: .5,
            scale: 10
        }
    });

    if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.position, commercialZone) == true) {
        alert("You are at the Main street");
    }
});
```

if you click on commercialZone (blue one), alert will be triggered

you can do what you want base on this

hope this helps